# Tar while excluding a directory

Tags: php, directory, tar

This is my PHP command to backup all of my `public_html files/folders` (which is currently working):

```
$command = "tar cvf ~/$filename ~/public_html/*";
```

Now, how would I exclude `public_html/backups/` from being included in the `tar.gz` file that is generated?

Comment: Here it is: http://bit.ly/wPGNPn

Answer (score 2):

By using the `--exclude` option? Please read the manual.

```
man tar
```

You can also use the `--exclude-tag-all` option.

Comment: You know, suggesting 'man tar' is not very helpful when 'man tar' yields the following less than helpful information:    
              "--exclude=PATTERN
              exclude files, given as a PATTERN"

Comment: "less than helpful", really? I think this answers the question completely... Is it the word PATTERN that makes you uncomfortable?

Answer (score 2):

Using the `--exclude` argument, which is [documented in the `tar` manual](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?tar).

```
$command = "tar --exclude '~/public_html/backups/' cvf ~/$filename ~/public_html/*";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `--exclude` argument when calling `tar`:

```
$command = "tar cvf ~/$filename --exclude='~/public_html/backups/' ~/public_html/*";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$command = "tar --exclude-from=exclude.txt  -cvf ~/$filename ~/public_html/*";
```

Tar will ignore files and folders, that match the patterns listed in file `exclude.txt`.

You can find more about this [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/exclude.html)